how to handle the return value of the write() of stream in nodejs
I have a question about the below Node.js documents.
First,as far as I tested, stream writer can controll the draining of it's buffer automatically based on the return value of write() and there is no need to handle the 'drain' event, which means stream writer will flush the buffer data by itself based on false value of write() and continue to write data to the buffer when write() returns true.
I am little confused. Is it mandatory to add any handler to stop the stream from writing more data to the buffer when write() returns false?

The below is from nodejs doducments
The return value is true if the internal buffer is less than the highWaterMark configured when the stream was created after admitting chunk.If false is returned, further attempts to write data to the stream should stop until the 'drain' event is emitted.
While a stream is not draining, calls to write() will buffer chunk, and return false. Once all currently buffered chunks are drained (accepted for delivery by the operating system), the 'drain' event will be emitted. Once write() returns false, do not write more chunks until the 'drain' event is emitted.
